# How do I show a selected button in a row by changing CSS in an HTML site?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div of buttons in line and I want the user to be able to see when they selected a button by changing the CSS and it only going back to its old state when they select another button. Is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but we need to see your HTML and CSS, and the Javascript you've attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find all the buttons and add event listener to execute some javascript where you put the logic of changing the behaviour of the buttons.

```js
// Find all the buttons through their class names
buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn")

// loop through all the buttons
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  let button = buttons[i];
  
  // Add click event to buttons
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
     
    // First remove 'clicked' class from all buttons
    buttons.forEach(function(item){
      item.classList.remove("clicked");
    })
    
    // Next add 'clicked' class to clicked button
    button.classList.add("clicked");
  });
}
```

```css
/* class added through javascript to the buttons to change appearance of clicked
 buttons */
.clicked {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button" class="btn">A</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn">B</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn">C</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
  $(".btn").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.btn{
  background:#111;
  border:none;
  padding:5px 10px;
  color:#fff;
}
.btn.active{
  background:#00cc00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Primary</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Success</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Info</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Warning</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Danger</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Link</button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Active state can be used for that. Assign all the button the same name so that they are linked. Hover can also be used.

Comment: If you add sample code to your answer it will help a lot to user.